# Animated show in which the main character could turn his arm into a giant cannon

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I'm trying to remember a name of a show. I can't remember when it aired though I'm guessing early 2000s is around the time frame.

The main character (MC) had an ability that turned his arm into a giant cannon through some nanotech virus stuff going through his body. The cannon arm loaded itself by launching the back end into the earth behind the MC and using the earth it ripped out as ammo. I can only remember that and the MC had brown/black hair and possibly wore something in orange.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? And was it animated or in live-action?

Comment: Animated I can't remember what year though early 2000's I'm guessing is around the time frame also thanks for the welcome

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[Generator Rex](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1636691/)*** (2010–2013)...?

> In a future where humans are infected by untested, microscopic robots, a young man with the ability to control the bots helps a government agency control the tech's vicious creations.

The main character, Rex Salazar, has nanites in his blood that allow him to transform his limbs into various weapons or transportation devices. One of the weapons he can form is the slam cannon, which is described below.

From the [Generator Rex Wiki](https://generatorrex.fandom.com/wiki/Rex_Salazar%27s_machines):

> The slam cannon is a large orange projectile cannon that Rex can transform either arm into. Similar to a rocket launcher, it is positioned to rest on his shoulder. However, it does not produce its own ammo; instead, a maw on the back end of the slam cannon can extend into the ground and reload solid material for ammunition. It then proceeds to fire the balled material at its target with great force.

You view a clip of Rex using the slam cannon at around the 12:24 mark in the video below.